# JOLT transformation for nested JSON?

Tags: json, jolt

I have a JSON that looks like this :

```
{
"Level1": {
    "Level2": {
        "val1": "Test",
        "val2": "Val"
    }
}
```

}

When I apply the followng Jolt shift transformation to this :

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "Level1": {
            "Level2": {
                "val1": "val001",
                "val2": "val002"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

I get the folliwng result :

```
    {
    "val001": "Test",
    "val002": "Val"
}
```

Why cant I see the **Level1, Level2** in the output? Please an someone help, I want to see that in the output too similar to whats the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in the shift spec usually refer to the location of the key in the output, so you'd need to include Level1 and Level2 in the values:

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "Level1": {
      "Level2": {
        "val1": "Level1.Level2.val001",
        "val2": "Level1.Level2.val002"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

If Level1 and/or Level2 can be arbitrary, you can use the @ operator to "go back up the tree" and get the values (see the Shiftr javadoc for examples).